why is my logic to conditionally rendering a loading screen not working?
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

//this is the whole method where I want to use it
const joinRoom = () => {
const roomKey = roomKeyInput.current.value;
if(roomKey == null)
  return
let req = {
  sessionId: sessionId,
  socketId: socket.id
}
setIsLoading(true)
axios.post(`${hostName}/join-room/${roomKey}`, req)
  .then((res)=>{
    if(res.data.success){
      setIsRoomAdmin(false)
      setRoomKey(res.data.roomKey)
      setConnectedToRoom(true);
      socket.emit('connect-to-room', {
        roomKey: roomKey
      })
    }
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
setIsLoading(false)
}

 return (
<>
  {isLoading && <Loader />}
</>
)

It works if I manually set the initial value to true, but on updating state it's not working.
I'm actually using this same logic in other component and this method is working fine there.
I know setting a state is asyncronous but, shouldn't this work may be with a little delay. I'm using Vite react btw. Sometimes I have to restart server to see the changes but I've tried that too.

axios.post run asyncronously. So setIsLoading(false) should be when it finish. Move it inside your function axios.post(...).then((...) => { ...here... }

const joinRoom = () => {
  // ...
  setIsLoading(true)
  axios
    .post(/*...*/)
  // ...
  setIsLoading(false)
}

You start the .post, but you aren't waiting for it to finish. As soon as it has been started, you set loading back to false, and so the loading screen never has a chance to show. You need to wait until you get a success response back (or an error);
setIsLoading(true)
axios.post(/*...*/)
  .then((res) => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    // ...

  }).catch(error => {
    setIsLoading(false);
    console.log(error);
  });


I should have known this but I guess I had a brainfart last night

Because axios's network requests are asynchronous and pushed to the microtask queue, your setState is written in the synchronous task code, so the setState is executed twice at once, so you need to wait for the network request to complete before you execute setState
